# pass additional parameters to Laravel Eloquent API Resources

Tags: laravel

I'm working with laravel api Resources and badly need to pass some additional parameters to api Resources

here i am pasting the code of my controller:

```
return response()->json([
   'countries' => CountryResource::collection($countries, 'en')
], 200);
```

here with the collection i am passing dummy data which i need in the Resource, remember there will be multiple numbers of parameters which needed to be passed to Resource.

Now let me paste the code of my Resource

```
private $language;

public function __construct($resource, $language)
{
    // Ensure you call the parent constructor
    parent::__construct($resource);
    $this->resource = $resource;

    $this->language = $language;
}


public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'language' => $this->language,
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
    ];
}
```

I am getting the data here in "language" variable but the issue is i'm not getting what i am passing it's showing me integers like "0","1" like this but i have passed "en"

i have tried many solutions from stackoverflow but not worked for me

Comment: You will need to [create a resource collection class](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) to customise the behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack overflow. You are on the right track but you forgot to add `id` and `name` to your `__construct`. It should look like this

```
private $language;
private $id;
private $name;

public function __construct($resource, $language,$id,$name)
{
    // Ensure you call the parent constructor
    parent::__construct($resource);
    $this->resource = $resource;

    $this->language = $language;
    $this->id = $id; 
    $this->name = $name;
}


public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'language' => $this->language,
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
    ];
}
```

Comment: I recommend passing an array to constructor so there will be no params order confusion: `__construct(array $params)` and retrieve them using `$params['..']`

Comment: @junaid id and name are coming through the $country array i have provided to the collection

Comment: @user8555937 buddy i have to get the value of language which i am passing the through the controller
let me explain i am passing 'en' from the controller  and getting 0,1 in the resource i want to get 'en' in the resource

Comment: @develoerzone here `CountryResource::collection($countries, 'en')` you are passing `en` to the constructor of your`CountryResource` which is why you are getting the `language` en. You need to explain what should be in the `id` and `name` of your resource.

Comment: Can you post what does the `$this->resource` holds?

Comment: @junaidrasheed i am not getting 'en' in the resource in i'm getting integers like 0,1 i just need to get the value of language what i am sending from the controller

Comment: @develoerzone at this point I'm gonna need some more code to help you out. Because your issue is not clear

Comment: As far as I see, people are trying to help without understanding the basics of Laravel API Resources. @develoerzone have you ever managed to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your model modify the code to this instead:

```
protected $language;

# appends language attribute to array
protected $appends = [
    'language'
];

# get language using accessor
public function getLanguageAttribute()
{
    return $this->language;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by mapping the model collection:

```php
return response()->json([
   'countries' => CountryResource::collection(
        $countries->map(fn ($country) => new CountryResource($country, 'en'))
    )
], 200);
```

Under the hood, the base Laravel class uses `tap()`.